# Broken images on Heroku - NodeJS React app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, webpack

I have a fullstack app built with NodeJS (Express), React and Webpack. When I run server locally and I serve public folder (into which Webpack generates assets), all images work properly. However, when the same assets are deployed to Heroku and the same script is used to run server on Heroku, images are broken.

For both local and Heroku server NODE_ENV is set to production.

The issue is not with hash, images name, browser cache or extension of image (png vs PNG). Images with .png extension are downloaded but not loaded at all while .jpg are loaded but they look as on attached screenshot.

Locally:
[image]

Any idea what is happening?

Comment: How do you load your images? Base64 string in `src`?

Comment: No, I load file like this: `<img src="fb8f767c715da437334228697d56b666.png" class="src-common-components-Header-Header__logo2--1y4Kj" alt="logo">`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that while doing `git push`, git converted line endings which leads to broken image data. To avoid it I changed configuration of `.gitattributes` and I added:

`*.png binary
*.jpg binary
*.jpeg binary
*.gif binary
*.ico binary
*.mov binary
*.mp4 binary
*.mp3 binary
*.flv binary
*.fla binary
*.swf binary
*.gz binary
*.zip binary
*.7z binary
*.ttf binary
*.eot binary
*.woff binary
*.pyc binary
*.pdf binary`

It works now :)